# Prevent execution of next ValidationAttributes on error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to prevent execution of next ValidationAttribute, if the first validation is failed?

For example, if (category "id" <= 0), then do not try to check if it exists.
Because now, when I do "PUT /api/categories/-1", I get this:

```
{
    "id": [
        "id must be greater or equal to 0",
        "Entity with such Id was not found!"
    ]
}
```

Method where I want to prevent further validation:

```cs
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public ActionResult UpdateCategory([Min(0)][CategoryExists] int id, [FromBody] Category category)
{
    return new OkResult();
    //if (category.Id == 0) {
    //    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Id property is required!");
    //}
    //_context.Category.Update(category);
    //_context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Min attribute

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MinAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int _minVal;

    public MinAttribute(int minVal)
    {
        _minVal = minVal;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if ((int)value >= _minVal)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return $"{name} must be greater or equal to {_minVal}";
    }
}
```

CategoryExists attribute

```cs
public class CategoryExistsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public CategoryExistsAttribute()
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var context = (TechDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(TechDbContext));
        var result = from i in context.Category
                        where i.Id == (int)value
                        select i;
        Category category = result.SingleOrDefault();
        if (category == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Entity with such Id was not found!");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an extension method for the `Category` object, which validates all your needs.

Eg

```
internal static bool Validate(this Category category){
if (category.Id <= 0) {
  return false;
    }
  // Add more validations or throw exceptions if needed.
  return true;
}
```

So from your controller you can do this.

```
if(category.Validate()){
  //proceed to other business logic
}
```

For more detailed information about data validation read [this](http://www.kamilgrzybek.com/design/rest-api-data-validation/)

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if I need to valide "id" from url or from request body, or even from both. Because in your answer you show how to validate "id" from request body. Maybe I should create extension method and pass "id" from url along with Category object, Validate(this Category category, int id) {}

Comment: Yes, use it from the object